# How to implement Judea Pearl's SCM model?

Tags: r, causality, dag

How could I implement Structural Causal Model (SCM) in R/STATA/SPSS?

I've read the first few chapters of Pearl's Causality and was fascinated by his SCM approach for causal inference.

And here is my question: Now I have a dataset and a DAG, how could I implement SCM? Are there any packages available for R/STATA/SPSS? And are there any tutorials or coding examples on this topic?

Comment: What do you mean by "implement" SCM? SCM is not a data analysis technique, it's a theoretical model of a causal system. Are you asking how to generate data based on an SCM? Or estimate the parameters of an SCM?

Comment: The Python `dowhy` package implements some features of the do-calculus - you might check that out.

Comment: For R, see the [dagitty](http://dagitty.net/primer/) and [causalimpact](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/causaleffect/index.html) (also [J. Stat. Soft.](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v076i12/v76i12.pdf) article) packages.